# How to customize and make website and mobile responsive the vertical menu

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have tried to embed a vertical menu bar on my Blogger website. But it seems like it's not responsive and the colour is not matching my website.

I need to remove the shadow and make the website responsive in mobile.

My website's background colour is white: https://codemyquestion.blogspot.com/

**This is how it is opened:**

[image]

**This is the expected output:**

[image]

**Below is the code:**

```html
<style>
    .ddsmoothmenu-v ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 130px;
     /* Main Menu Item widths */
        list-style-type: none;
        font: bold 12px Verdana;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .downarrowclass {
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        right: 7px;
    }
    
    .rightarrowclass {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 5px;
    }
        /* Top level menu links style */
    .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a {
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
            /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
        height: 32px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #778;
        border-right: 0px solid #778;
    }
    
    .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:link, .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:visited, .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:active {
        color: white;
        background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-VCtcZunZJ2U/T9W7MM1uIXI/AAAAAAAAB9o/yVJ0Cad3Q0g/s1600/tab_bg.gif);
        height: 22px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: left center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    
    .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a.selected {
            /*CSS class that's dynamically added to the currently active menu items' LI A element*/
        color: white;
        background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-F0-PrDUYlX4/T9W7MrjME5I/AAAAAAAAB9w/0CLQurrHUjM/s1600/tabhover_bg.gif);
        height: 22px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: left center;
    }
    
    .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:hover {
        color: white;
        background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-F0-PrDUYlX4/T9W7MrjME5I/AAAAAAAAB9w/0CLQurrHUjM/s1600/tabhover_bg.gif);
        height: 22px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: left center;
    }
        /*Sub level menu items */
    .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li ul {
        position: absolute;
        width: 170px;
            /*Sub Menu Items width */
        height: 22px;
        top: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
        /* Holly Hack for IE \*/
    * html .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li {
        float: left;
        height: 1%;
    }
    
    * html .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a {
        height: 1%;
    }
    /*======= Vertical Drop Down Menu By Helper Blogger ========= */
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://helperblogger.ucoz.com/code/hb-smooth-menu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        })
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ddsmoothmenu.init({
    
            mainmenuid: "smoothmenu2",
            //Menu DIV id
            orientation: 'v',
            //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
            classname: 'ddsmoothmenu-v',
            //class added to menu's outer DIV
    
            //customtheme: ["#804000", "#482400"],
            contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
        })
    </script>
    <div id="smoothmenu2" class="ddsmoothmenu-v">
         <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.helperblogger.com/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Folder 0</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Folder 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Folder 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item 2.1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.helperblogger.com/">Create This</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br style="clear: left" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the black white nav menu:

HTML

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> About</a>
  <a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Services</a>
  <a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Contact</a>
  <div href="#" class="dropdown-btn">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Dropdown
    <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Search</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 58px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 20px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidenav:hover {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x:visible;
}
.sidenav .fa:not(.fa-caret-right){
    margin-right:20px;
}

.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position:relative;
}
.dropdown-btn:hover .dropdown-container{
    display:block;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  left:100%;
  margin-top:-30px;
}

.fa-caret-right {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
  display:none !important;
}
```

the sub-menu opens to the right side, if you want to open it from the left side use this code:

HTML

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> About</a>
  <a href="#services"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Services</a>
  <a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Contact</a>
  <div href="#" class="dropdown-btn">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
    Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Search</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidenav {
  direction:rtl;
  height: 100%;
  width: 58px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 20px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidenav:hover {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x:visible;
}
.sidenav .fa:not(.fa-caret-left){
    margin-left:20px;
}

.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position:relative;
}
.dropdown-btn:hover .dropdown-container{
    display:block;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-right: 8px;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  right:100%;
  margin-top:-30px;
}

.fa-caret-right {
  float: left;
  display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: : Thanks .. in future if i wan to make it fixed static the property of float : to fixed it will work right

Comment: you need to do some changes or you can check w3school for that

Comment: : Yes i am checking on w3school the code works like charm , it will be helpful if you add that code as well .. where the box is static no sliding happening some might required that way for their website ... for me the above one work like charm Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I recently made my online web-game mobile responsive too. I can help:

1. The problem is **px**. Don't use px for mobile websites. Instead, use percent (%) or viewport-width (vw) these will make it so the elements will resize to the browser size.
2. Absolute positioning. It will override the width of the page if the elements are not inside a div. If it's in a div, It'll not follow the width of that div. Instead, use `position: relative` because this is relative to the width or height of the viewport page.
3. Try resizing your browser on your laptop/desktop, and notice the elements match. Next:
4. Use the CSS3 `max-width` property so on laptop, it'll look fine. **But** on mobile devices it'll probably look like a smaller version of the desktop sized screen. For example:
   [image: random website screenshot]

will look the same on a mobile device but smaller.

Now, finally, you can use: `<meta>` HTML tag. It definitely works on texts, images, Etc. Here's how:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

use these tricks and your website is ready for mobile devices.

**Edit:** I saw your website. Everything looks fine on my laptop.
What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make some changes in your style

```
<style>
.ddsmoothmenu-v ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 130px;
 /* Main Menu Item widths */
    list-style-type: none;
    font: bold 12px Verdana;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
}

.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.downarrowclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 7px;
    transform:rotateY(180deg); /* change the right arrow to left arrow */
}

.rightarrowclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
    transform:rotateY(180deg); /* change the right arrow to left arrow */
}
    /* Top level menu links style */
.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
        /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
    height: 32px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #778;
    border-right: 0px solid #778;
}

.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:link, .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:visited, .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:active {
    color: white;
    background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-VCtcZunZJ2U/T9W7MM1uIXI/AAAAAAAAB9o/yVJ0Cad3Q0g/s1600/tab_bg.gif);
    height: 22px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left center;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a.selected {
        /*CSS class that's dynamically added to the currently active menu items' LI A element*/
    color: white;
    background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-F0-PrDUYlX4/T9W7MrjME5I/AAAAAAAAB9w/0CLQurrHUjM/s1600/tabhover_bg.gif);
    height: 22px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left center;
}

.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-F0-PrDUYlX4/T9W7MrjME5I/AAAAAAAAB9w/0CLQurrHUjM/s1600/tabhover_bg.gif);
    height: 22px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left center;
}
    /*Sub level menu items */
.ddsmoothmenu-v ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
        /*Sub Menu Items width */
    height: 22px;
    top: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    visibility: hidden;
    left:-170px !important; /* move the sub-menu to the left */
    box-shadow:none !important; /* remove the shadow */
}
    /* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 1%;
}

* html .ddsmoothmenu-v ul li a {
    height: 1%;
}
/*======= Vertical Drop Down Menu By Helper Blogger ========= */
</style>
```

Comment: : Awesome bro thanks .. it is possible for you to make the box black and inside content white like this :  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown

Comment: @rixeh46662 you're welcome,
do you want it as fixed menu or as a nav menu

Comment: : No not a fix menu because i am emending as html/css widget  so i want to make the container black the insode content white .. i tried to use this but not working : background-color: #111;   ... i want it as nav menu

Comment: : This website code i am trying to emdedd my whole website content become abonormal all text got bigger : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown

Comment: the above code which i posted is working like charm just need the modification like i said above